# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what(): std::bad_alloc"

Tags: c++

What is the reason for this error?Actually I dont want to get affected by the previous testcase result so at beginning of test case,I emptied the queue so that each test case could get fresh start. 
 "

```
#include <iostream>      
#include <queue> 
using namespace std;   
int main()
{
queue <int> first;
queue <int> empty;
queue <int> second;
int i,j,k,l,n,m,a,p,q;
int test,t;
std::cin>>test;
t=test;
  while(test--)
     {

        swap(first,empty);
        swap(second,empty);

       std::cin>>n>>m;
       a=2*n;
         for(i=1;i<=a;i++)
                 {
                    first.push(i);
                 }
          for(i=a+1;i<=m;i++)
                   {
                     second.push(i);
                   }
       for(i=1;i<=a;i++)
             {
               p=second.front();
                second.pop();
                   cout<<p;
              q=first.front();
                  first.pop();
                     cout<<q;
              }

   }
 }
```

Comment: Considering you have a number of cin calls, what is the input you provide when the bad_alloc is thrown? Providing a large enough values for either n or m would cause a bad_alloc.

Comment: you make a `first.front and first.pop()` and you don't check if the queue first is empty or not. check the second too. read the queue on cppreference, it would probably help you.
[link]http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/pop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is in the lines,

```
swap(first, empty);
swap(second, empty);
```

When the first swap is called, 'empty' gets 'first' (and 'first' becomes 'empty'). Now, when the second swap is called, empty is no longer vacant (It has 'first').

To solve this problem, 
One solution could be,

```
first = queue<int> ();
second = queue<int> ();
```

to empty the queues.

Another solution could be to write,

```
first = empty;
second = empty;
```